# Can't set up the redirection just by editing the hosts file

Tags: file, redirect, iis, dns, hosts

So, I was trying to redirect this website www.segrepass2.unina.it to localhost
-I set up the localhost with IIS and it works.
- I tested with multiple other websites and it works.
It's not a problem of SSL or something because not only I tested with https websites of course, but I used redirector to guide the traffic from https to http.
It just seems that it can't work with this website in particular and it sounds really odd to me.

Thank you so much for your answers!

Comment: Edit your question to include more details please. Keep in mind no one can see your screen, so use proper screen shots to show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Could you find that failed request in IIS log or C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR? What subs-status code did you see in IIS log. It is appreciated if you could post more details.